# Chaining and queuing ajax requests using jQuery deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I have a clunky ajax queue that uses setTimeout and a global flag:

```
var InProgress = false;

function SendAjax(TheParameters) {

  if (InProgress) {
     setTimeout(function () { SendAjax(TheParameters) } , 500) 
  }

  InProgress = true;

  $.ajax({
    ...
    data: TheParameters,
    complete: InProgress = false
  });
}
```

How can I rewrite this using a queuing mechanism so that the requests trigger one after the other in the order they're received?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `then` we can chain each request sequentially as they come in.

```
var previousPromise;

// This actually sends the request
function actualSender(params) {
  return $.ajax(...);
}

// This will make sure that the next request will be fired
// when the previous one finishes.
function SendAjax(TheParameters) {
  if (previousPromise) {
    // Even if the previous request has finished, this will work.
    previousPromise = previousPromise.then(function () {
      return actualSender(TheParameters);
    });
    return previousPromise;
  }

  // first time
  previousPromise = actualSender(TheParameters);
  return previousPromise;
}
```

**I didn't test this but the idea should work**

Comment: What happens if there multiple requests that come in simultaneously? Wouldn't an array of queued requests work better?

Comment: No, because the promises gets chained.

Comment: I'm always amazed by the simplicity of jquery's power. Let me test it and I'll get back.

Comment: It's actually promises. ;)

Comment: Does that mean that the line previousPromise = previousPromise.then(..) adds a promise to the existing promise?

Comment: Yes, you got it. :)

Comment: This is the most amazing piece of code: all over the web there are answers that are pages of code long and in just a few line, you've figured out how to queue requests!!! This code works perfectly and over time will become the authority on how to queue requests. Thank you sooooo much!!

Comment: You're very welcome. Basically just exploiting how promises works. :)